# spring entity : return id of created record

Tags: java, spring, entity

I have this `AccountantRepository` class

```
@Repository("accountantRepository")
@Transactional
public interface AccountantRepository extends JpaRepository<Accountant, Long>
```

In `AccountantServiceImpl`

```
@Service("accountantService")
public class AccountantServiceImpl implements AccountantService{

    @Autowired
    private AccountantRepository accountantRepository;

    @Override
    public Accountant saveAccountant(Accountant newAccountant, String role) {
        return accountantRepository.save(newAccountant);
    }
}
```

when i do this `accountantRepository.save(newAccountant);`

how do I obtain the id of the newly created record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the returned instance by `JpaRepository.save()`. It will contain the `id` valued.

The [`CrudRepository.save()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-) method (where `save()` is declared) specifies :

> Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation
>   might have changed the entity instance completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly take the id from the entity itself. `newAccountant.getId()`( or what ever be the field) will return the data after save method has been called . 
Shown below-

```
 @Override
    public int saveAccountant(Accountant newAccountant, String role) {
        accountantRepository.save(newAccountant);

return newAccountant.getId();
    }
```

This reference will be available in hibernate session and hibernate will set the id to the persisited object.