# Spring WebFlux - Populate Id of new entity in using REST on view

Tags: javascript, spring-webflux

My question is somewhat related to this question (but I am using WebFlux) -
[spring entity : return id of created record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648109/spring-entity-return-id-of-created-record)

My Entity:

```
    @Table
    public class Todo {
        @Id
        private Long id;
        private String text;
        private boolean completed;
        ...Getters Setters...
    }
```

My Repository (Reactive):

```
public interface TodoRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Todo, Long> {

    Flux<Todo> findAll();
    
    Flux<Todo> findByText(String text);
    
}
```

I have a Spring WebFlux's RestController like below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
class TodoController { 
private TodoRepository repository;
......   
@PostMapping("/todo")
        Mono<Todo> addTodo(@RequestBody Todo todo) {
            logger.info("Creating New Todo...");
            return repository.save(todo).log();
            //return repository.save(todo);
        }
}
```

On the view in JS (responsible for POSTing), I have the following:

```
    function insertNewRecord(formData) {
    fetch('/api/todo', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ id: formData.todoid, text: formData.todotext, completed: formData.todocompleted })
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.status >= 400 && response.status < 600) {
            throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        if (response.status === 200) {
            alert('Entry Successful.. ! \nTable will be reloaded now.!');
            //reloadRecords();
            var table = document.getElementById("dataTable").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
            var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
            
            // WHAT SHOULD I DO IN PLACE OF BELOW TWO LINES TO GET ID OF NEW ENTITY?

            cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
            cell1.innerHTML = formData.todoid;

            cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = formData.todotext;
            cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
            cell3.innerHTML = formData.todocompleted;
            cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
            cell4.innerHTML = `<a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning mr-3" onClick="onEdit(this)">Edit</a>
                       <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onClick="onDelete(this)">X</a>`;



        }
        // alert(response.status);
    })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Your error is here!
            alert(error)
        });
}
```

Using above post request from JS ([here](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootReactiveH2DB/blob/main/src/main/resources/static/js/crud.js), line # 20-56), the new entry is saved in the backend successfully. No issues here at all till this point.

My Form and table on the Thymeleaf template:

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();onFormSubmit();"
            autocomplete="off">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-md-2 text-right font-weight-bold">
                    <label for="todoid" class="form-label">Id</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                            name="todoid" id="todoid" readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-md-2 text-right font-weight-bold">
                    <label for="todotext" class="form-label">Description</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                            name="todotext" id="todotext">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-md-2 text-right font-weight-bold">
                    <label for="todocompleted" class="form-label">Completed?</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <select class="form-select form-control-sm" name="todocompleted"
                            id="todocompleted">
                            <option value="true">True</option>
                            <option selected value="false">False</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row mt-3 mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold"></div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"
                        class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block">
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    <div class="row mt-3 mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold"></div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <table class="table table-sm table-striped" id="dataTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Completed?</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="appDataTable2"></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, the html table is populated without the Id of the new entity/entry like this:

[image]

But this is what I expect to happen. i.e. populate the newly generated id too with the same request. I.e. without reloading the entire list/table or refreshing the page:

[image]

I am lost here. Any relevant example's link or clue on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this impossible to answer, since we have no idea of any of your code. You have not posted anything about what your entities look like, the code for you html table, debug logs, what you are fetching from the database, what you are returning to the client. All logs of all the requests? And dont link to your code, include the relevant code parts in your question and preferably with enough code so that we can reproduce the problem. Voted to close due to lack of debugging details.

Comment: Can you be specific what you need? I can provide.Or this question will be closed down now?

Comment: read the question yourself, do you consider you have left enough information for anyone to reproduce the problem in their own IDEA? The code snippets you have provided arnt even runnable.

Comment: Okay. Will update the question with Entity, JS and HTML all together. Thanks Thomas.

Comment: Updated all the required info as asked by Thomas. Thanks for your pointers @Thomas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is quite simple you are using the object `formData` to populate your table, which is the data that is input in your html-form.

You have to use the returned data from the backend.

So this line doesnt work `cell1.innerHTML = formData.todoid;`, there is no value in the id field, because that data is set by the backend.

```
fetch('https://foobar.com', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(someData),
})
.then(response => response.json()) // extract json from response
.then(data => {
  
   ...

   cell1.innerHTML = data.id;   // use the returned data

   ...
})
```

This is the reason we need to see the entire codebase. Because this part of code was never posted by you in the first place.

Comment: Man !!. Yeah its as simple as you said. It worked with `cell1.innerHTML = data.id;` as I had id in my Entity and hence response. Thanks a ton for your help.